# OracleCommand Update works with interpolated SQL, but not with Parameterized

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, parameterized-query, oraclecommand

I'm doing some maintenance on a legacy app uses OracleConnection and OracleCommand to manage our data.  I'm Having an issue where a specific update isn't working when I use parameters, but if I convert the same statement to an interpolated string, it's working fine.  I'm not getting any exceptions, the update just doesn't happen, and returns a 0 for rows updated.  I'm doing other updates with parameters, so I'm curious if anyone sees anything that I might have missed with this one.  I've tried with/without the transaction as well as explicitly creating OracleParameter objects to no effect.

The method is below.  I've left the parameterized version and the parameter setting commented out for reference.

```
    public int UpdateBusinessEntitlement(int appId, int businessId, int entitlementTypeId, string sso)
    {

        // Non-Working Parameterized Version
        //var sql = "UPDATE APD.APD_BUS_TO_APP_MAP " +
        //                   "SET ENTITLEMENT_TYPE_SEQ_ID = :entitlementTypeId, " +
        //                   "LAST_UPDATE_DATE = SYSDATE, " +
        //                   "LAST_UPDATED_BY = :lastUpdatedBy " +
        //                   "WHERE APP_SEQ_ID = :appId AND BUSINESS_SEQ_ID = :businessId";

        var sql = "UPDATE APD.APD_BUS_TO_APP_MAP " +
               $"SET ENTITLEMENT_TYPE_SEQ_ID = {entitlementTypeId}, " +
               "LAST_UPDATE_DATE = SYSDATE, " +
               $"LAST_UPDATED_BY = {sso} " +
               $"WHERE APP_SEQ_ID = {appId} AND BUSINESS_SEQ_ID = {businessId}";


        using (var cn = _connectionBuilder.GetUpdaterConnection())
        {
            using (var cmd = _connectionBuilder.GetCommand(sql, cn))
            {
                cn.Open();
                var transaction = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;

                //cmd.Parameters.Add("appId", appId);
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("businessId", businessId);
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("entitlementTypeId", entitlementTypeId);
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("lastUpdatedBy", sso);


                var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                transaction.Commit();

                return rows;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are binding parameters by position rather than name.

By position, you'd be putting appId first into entitlement_type_seq_id. Then BusinessId into last_Updated_By, entitlementTypeId into app_seq_id and lastUpdatedBy into business_seq_id.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleCommandClass.htm#i997666

Comment: Thank you!  This fixed my problem.  I didn't realize that it was binding by position by default.  I'll appreciate the link to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to set

```
cmd.BindByName = true;
```

because default value for `BindByName` property is `false`, which means the parameters are bound by position.

Or you have to use the same order of parameters as they appear in your statement, i.e.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("entitlementTypeId", entitlementTypeId);
cmd.Parameters.Add("lastUpdatedBy", sso);
cmd.Parameters.Add("appId", appId);
cmd.Parameters.Add("businessId", businessId);
```

btw, usually OracleParameter are added like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("entitlementTypeId", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = entitlementTypeId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("lastUpdatedBy", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = entitlementTypeId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("appId", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = appId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("businessId", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = businessId;
```

I assume for simple data types like numbers of string the syntax does not matter, however other data type (e.g. *Date*) may fail if you simply use `cmd.Parameters.Add(string name, object val)`.

Comment: Thank you!  This fixed my problem.  I didn't realize that it was binding by position by default.  I'll read through the docs that Gary posted, and change my parameters to the new format.